# Is there an audio recording for all of Nishmat Kol Chai?

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, recording

My favourite prayer in the siddur is Nishmat Kol Chai. However, as a non-Hebrew speaker (I can read the letters phonetically), I find the length of the text intimidating. In addition, since it is always chanted silently in synagogue, there isn't much opportunity to learn the Hebrew from listening to others.

I wondered if there is an audio recording available with a reading of this prayer, or singing it if there is a tune. I've never heard a tune for the whole prayer, but it would make it a lot easier to learn if there was one.

It would be really helpful to have a recording of the whole text even if it isn't with a tune. Then I can listen to that over and over again to internalize the Hebrew.

Comment: Hi Avi, what is your minhag? Ashkenazi? Sefardi? Can you be even more specific? I'll try and find a good example to fit your custom

Comment: Thank you! I'm Ashkenazi.

Comment: @RabbiKaii *sefaradi

Comment: thanks @Aaron. Avi, I am sorry, I have been trying but it's hard to find a good version that's easy to use to learn it for nusach Ashkenaz (surprising amount for Sefaradi). If I come across it I will definitely post it

Comment: @RabbiKaii If you know of a recording in other another nusach that would still be a big help. The main thing is to learn the words and think they are most the same between the different traditions.

Comment: @AviC well yes, they are mostly the same, but have a few fairly big differences. The pronunciation will also be different, but here's a really clear reading in sefaradi, with text on screen, if you have access to youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1j0T0KFAu8. I won't make into a proper answer as I'd like to find an ashkenazi version ideally

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thanks so much, I look forward to watching / listening to the video.

Answer (score 1):

These two sites have a wide selection of audio resources for different versions of part or all of Nishmas:

- https://www.nli.org.il/he/piyut/Piyut1media_010069500285705171/NLI
- https://offtonic.com/nusach/index.html?nid=15&sidpath=&sid=3846&o=1

If you have any problems with the Hebrew content on the first link, then you can use your web browser's option (eg. in Chrome) to translate the page to English as this might help to some degree.

Also see [this related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30240/resource-for-tunes-for-prayers-songs) for other ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the links.